# Synonymize [tile] with [tiles]

Tags: discussion

[tiles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiles) has [537 questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiles). The second tag, [tile](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tile) has [65 questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tile) and additionally has no tag wiki or excerpt. It appears to cover the same things as tiles. Should they be synonymized?

Comment: I have done this.

Comment: @Vaillancourt thank you! Appreciated. Hope you are doing well.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt there is an expert in a single **tile** that could use the tag [tile](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tile) to filter out questions he might want to answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed this situation today with a question that had tags for both. I would have [proposed a synonym](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/tile/synonyms) myself, but I lack the necessary topic rep to do so.