# Question appears in "Hot" thread but not the "Active" thread

Tags: bug

Even after a refresh, I noted that [my newest Meta question](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/synonymize-tile-with-tiles) did not appear in the "Active" thread, but did appear in the "Hot" thread immediately after posting, even with only one view. Are these two threads swapped on the meta site? I haven't noticed this on the main site, but it could be happening there as well.

[image: Active thread]

[image: Hot thread]

Edit:

The "Active" thread now seems to have updated after a few minutes of keeping an eye on it. What could have caused this?

Comment: Because that's how the technology works.

Comment: [Blame caching.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)